# In Python, trying to convert geocoded tsv file into geojson format

Tags: python, json, geocoding, geojson, csv

trying to convert a geocoded TSV file into JSON format but i'm having trouble with it. Here's the code:

```
import geojson
import csv

def create_map(datafile):
    geo_map = {"type":"FeatureCollection"}
    item_list = []
    datablock = list(csv.reader(datafile))
    for i, line in enumerate(datablock):
        data = {}
        data['type'] = 'Feature'
        data['id'] = i
        data['properties']={'title': line['Movie Title'],
                           'description': line['Amenities'],
                           'date': line['Date']}
        data['name'] = {line['Location']}
        data['geometry'] = {'type':'Point',
                           'coordinates':(line['Lat'], line['Lng'])}
        item_list.append(data)
    for point in item_list:
        geo_map.setdefault('features', []).append(point)
    with open("thedamngeojson.geojson", 'w') as f:
        f.write(geojson.dumps(geo_map))

create_map('MovieParksGeocode2.tsv')
```

I'm getting a `TypeError:list indices must be integers, not str` on the `data['properties']` line but I don't understand, isn't that how I set values to the geoJSON fields?

The file I'm reading from has values under these keys: Location Movie Title Date    Amenities   Lat Lng

The file is viewable here: https://github.com/yongcho822/Movies-in-the-park/blob/master/MovieParksGeocodeTest.tsv

Thanks guys, much appreciated as always.

Comment: What's in your data file?

Comment: Do you have to do this in Python? If not, you can use ogr2ogr.

Comment: this is my data file @Ajay https://github.com/yongcho822/Movies-in-the-park/blob/master/MovieParksGeocode2.tsv

Comment: @tdihp what the heck is ogr2ogr?

Comment: @SpicyClubSauce http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html convert geospatial data between formats known by OGR, if you can open your tsv file with qgis correctly, you can use this tool to convert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple things going on here that need to get fixed.

1.Your TSV contains newlines with double quotes. I don't think this is intended, and will cause some problems.

```
Location    Movie Title Date    Amenities   Formatted_Address   Lat Lng
"
Edgebrook Park, Chicago "   A League of Their Own   7-Jun   "
Family friendly activities and games. Also: crying is allowed." Edgebrook Park, 6525 North Hiawatha Avenue, Chicago, IL 60646, USA  41.9998876  -87.7627672
"
```

2.You don't need the `geojson` module to dump out JSON - which is all GeoJSON is. Just `import json` instead.

3.You are trying to read a TSV, but you don't include the `delimiter=\t` option that is needed for that.

4.You are trying to read keys off the rows, but you aren't using `DictReader` which does that for you.Hence the `TypeError` about indices you mention above.

Check out my revised code block below..you still need to fix your TSV to be a valid TSV.

```
import csv
import json

def create_map(datafile):
    geo_map = {"type":"FeatureCollection"}
    item_list = []
    with open(datafile,'r') as tsvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(tsvfile,delimiter='\t')
        for i, line in enumerate(reader):
            print line
            data = {}
            data['type'] = 'Feature'
            data['id'] = i
            data['properties']={'title': line['Movie Title'],
                               'description': line['Amenities'],
                               'date': line['Date']}
            data['name'] = {line['Location']}
            data['geometry'] = {'type':'Point',
                               'coordinates':(line['Lat'], line['Lng'])}
            item_list.append(data)
        for point in item_list:
            geo_map.setdefault('features', []).append(point)
        with open("thedamngeojson.geojson", 'w') as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(geo_map))

create_map('MovieParksGeocode2.tsv')
```

Comment: thanks for the great revision! i'm curious though, i drafted up my json 'fields'/keys totally based off a walk-thru model i did earlier with it. Couldn't find a proper json format 'fields' guide.. am I doing that correctly with the data['properties'], data['name'] etc?

Comment: Not exactly...I'd suggest reading over the official GeoJSON spec at http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html.

Comment: After passing in the properly formatted TSV file the error i'm getting with your script is 

`TypeError: set(['Edgebrook Park, Chicago ']) is not JSON serializable.` I placed a `print item_list` right before the `geo_map.setdefault('features', []).append(point)` and the item_list printed out all fine so I have to figure the error is coming with the latter line.

Comment: Can you update the TSV on the gist with your revisions?

Comment: done: https://github.com/yongcho822/Movies-in-the-park/blob/master/MovieParksGeocodeTest.tsv

Comment: I also ran a `print 'Done'` right above the `with open("thedamngeojson.geojson", 'w') as f:` and it printed out fine, guess that means the geo_map.setdefault actually went fine and it's the actual writing of the file to JSON that went wrong at the end?

Comment: Drop the brackets around `{line['Location']}` in the `data['name']` line. Although that key should be in the `properties` hash anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78572/discussion-between-spicyclubsauce-and-snkashis).